# Countdown timer using js

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Need to create a countdown timer for a online quiz. 
Timer should start as soon as user enters web-page.

Tried this piece of code.

```
<
script >
    var fiveMinutes = 3600;
var display = document.getElementById('time');
var myTimer;

function startTime(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;

    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (diff <= 0) {
            display.textContent = "TIME IS UP!";
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    };
    timer();
    myTimer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function() {
    startTime(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Counting is required not from the current moment, but from the date specified in the startTime variable. Let's consider for your convenience that it has exactly the same format as the return value of Date.now ().

i need to get a variable, give it some value (not Date.now ()), and use it as a starting point

thanks beforehand

Comment: so what ? where is the problem ?

Comment: there is no problem, actually. I just need to change a bit. idk how to do it. "Counting is required not from the current moment, but from the date specified in the startTime variable. Let's consider for your convenience that it has exactly the same format as the return value of Date.now ().

i need to get a variable, give it some value (not Date.now ()), and use it as a starting point "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is a simple count down timer that displays the time in the window.

```js
const display = document.getElementById('time');
const fiveminutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;

function timer(endTime) {
  var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let diff = endTime - now;
    let minutes = Math.floor(diff % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor(diff % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (diff <= 0) {
      display.textContent = "TIME IS UP!";
      clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
  }, 100);
}

window.onload = timer(new Date().getTime() + fiveminutes);
```

```css
span {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span id="time"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. This will trigger when the user enters the page.  Your comment is confusing though. Do you want this to start when page loads or at a certain time based on a variable?

```
window.onload(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    // whatever you want to happen after 3600
    // i.e. disable input fields for quiz
    }, 3600);
}
```

Comment: thank you. everything works fine in the code, i just need to change it in the way i described below the code. that is what i cant implement

Comment: If you need it to trigger "Timer should start as soon as user enters web-page.", then why add the extra complexity. It's going to take some thought to create what you're talking about. You either need a back-end server to pool for the correct starting time, or have javascript do it in the browser. I would suggest you rethink your approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I'd been working on that I adapted to try to provide a solution for you here. It's still buggy, but maybe it will give you some ideas, and I'll try to edit it when I have some more time. (I expected to have it working by now but need some rest.)

```js
const
  timeInput = document.getElementById("timeInput"),  
  nowBtn = document.getElementById("nowBtn"),
  durationInput = document.getElementById("durationInput"),
  confirmBtn = document.getElementById("confirmBtn"),
  display = document.getElementById("display");

let
  startTime,
  timeRemaining,
  chronos;


document.addEventListener("click", setUpTimer);
timeInput.addEventListener("focus", ()=>{ nowBtn.checked = false; });

function setUpTimer(event){
  
  // Makes sure the button was the target of the click before proceeding
  if(event.target == confirmBtn){
    if(nowBtn.checked){ // Puts the current time in the time input
      const
        clickTime = new Date(),
        hours = clickTime.getHours();
      let minutes = clickTime.getMinutes();
      clickTime.setSeconds(clickTime.getSeconds() + 1);
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      timeInput.value = `${hours}:${minutes}`;
    }
    const
      timeInputValue = timeInput.value,
      durationInputValue = durationInput.value;
    // Validates input (or complains and aborts)
    if(!timeInputValue || !durationInputValue){
      display.innerHTML = "Please choose a start time and duration"
      clearInterval(chronos);
      return;
    }
    const
      startArray = timeInputValue.split(":"),
      startHours = parseInt(startArray[0]),
      startMinutes = parseInt(startArray[1]),
      durationInMinutes = parseInt(durationInput.value),
      now = new Date();

    // Updates global variables that `countdown` function will need
    timeRemaining = durationInMinutes * 60;
    startTime = new Date();
    startTime.setHours(startHours, startMinutes);
    // In case startTime is supposed to be tomorrow
    const
      nowHrs = now.getHours(),
      strtHrs = startTime.getHours()
      nowMins = now.getMinutes(),
      strtMins = startTime.getMinutes();
    // If it looks like the hour already passed, it's probably an earlier hour tomorrow
    if(strtHrs < nowHrs || (strtHrs == nowHrs && strtMins < nowMins)){
      startTime.setDate(startTime.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Announces successful timer setup and resets inputs
    const
      displayedHours = startTime.getHours(),
      storedMinutes = startTime.getMinutes(),
      displayedMinutes = storedMinutes < 10 ? "0" + storedMinutes : storedMinutes;
    display.innerHTML = `A ${durationInMinutes}-minute timer will start ` +       `at ${displayedHours}:${displayedMinutes}`;
    timeInput.value = "";
    nowBtn.checked = false;
    durationInput.value = "5";



    // `setInterval` calls `countdown` function every second

    console.log(startTime.toLocaleString());
    clearInterval(chronos);
    chronos = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

  }
}

function countdown(){

  if(timeRemaining <= 0){
    display.innerHTML = "TIME IS UP!";
    clearInterval(chronos);
  }
  else{
    const now = new Date();
    if(now.getTime() >= startTime.getTime()){
      updateDisplayedTime(timeRemaining--);
    }
  }
}

function updateDisplayedTime(totalSeconds){
  let
    minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60),
    seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  display.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

```css
.inputContainer{ margin-bottom: 1em; }
#display{ font-size: 1.7em;}
#nowBtn {margin-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
  <label>
    <div>Start timer at: </div>
    <input type="time" id="timeInput" />
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type ="checkbox" id="nowBtn" />
    <span>Now</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
  <label>
    <div>Duration (minutes): </div>
    <input type="number" value="5" id="durationInput" min="1" max="1440" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="inputContainer">
  <button id="confirmBtn">Confirm</button>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```